# How to set up a transparent proxy on my home network

Tags: networking, server, proxy, dhcp

So I'm still a beginner in terms of setting up servers, and I have some questions regarding the way that the server gets hit.

So my current network architecture looks like this:

```
[internet] <-> [router] <-> [other devices]
```

where other devices are devices that are connected either by WiFi, or through ethernet cables to the router. One of these devices is a local box running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which will be the server.

Now here's what I want to do. I want to set up an instance of Squid to run as a transparent proxy for all connections (on my server box). To do this I realize that in some way the router has to know that it has to send all incoming/outgoing traffic going to other devices to the server first so that the server can hand them over to Squid for processing.

That's the part that confuses me a bit. Can this be done with my current network architecture? I've read online that you can disable DHCP on the router, and then run DHCP on the server box, which will then allow you to automatically configure proxy settings. I'm unsure of how to do this though.

If I can't run this with my current architecture, will I need to upgrade it to look like this?:

```
[internet] <-> [router] <-> [server] <-> [other devices]
```

If that's the case, how can I make all WiFi traffic also go through the server (as WiFi devices connect directly to the router).

Also, are there any pitfalls or caveats that I need to be aware of while setting this up, and are there any guides you can recommend that would get me through this process quicker?

Comment: Did you find anything?